# RexExp min and max

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to validate min 1 and max 59 with the following regexp but not working as expected.

```
 ^[1-5]?[1-9]$
```

What is wrong with the expression?

Comment: We have comparison operators provided by JavaScript. And this is the best situation to use them. `if (num >=1 && num <= 59)`

Comment: For example `10,20,30,40` and `50` are not matched by your regex. Use one of Tushars suggestions.

Comment: **Still** want to use RegEx? But Why? Anyway, you can use [`^([1-5][0-9]|[1-9])$`](https://regex101.com/r/pT6dO3/1)

Comment: Tushar's solution works.

Comment: I hope you used the first one

Comment: You've almost got it backwards. It should be `^[1-9]|[1-5]\d$`

Answer (score 2):

It's work: `^([1-5][0-9]|[1-9])$` (@Tushar)

```
if (/^([1-5][0-9]|[1-9])$/.test(number)) {
    // Successful match
} else {
    // Match attempt failed
}
```

The better/faster way (without regex):

```
function validate(number) {
    number = parseInt(number);
    return number > 0 && number < 60;
}

for (var i = 0; i < 65; i++) {
    console.log(validate(i));
}
```

Tested:

[image]

Comment: @RedLaser Right, I was missed some test cases.

Comment: @Oleander I fixed my regex.

Comment: **Suggestions:** **1.** Don't need `?` **2.** Don't need capturing groups `()` **3.** `m` flag is not required.

Comment: [`^[1-5][0-9]|[1-9]$`](https://regex101.com/r/pT6dO3/2) is not working. Check bottom in the demo. [You can use this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35393917/rexexp-min-and-max#comment58491761_35393917)

Comment: Use `^(?:[1-5][0-9]|[1-9])$`

Answer (score 1):

Everyone busy trying to provide a solution missed the real question OP asked.

> What is wrong with the expression?

Well here is your regex: `^[1-5]?[1-9]$`

What you are trying to do is match a number having first digit (optional) in range `1 to 5` and second digit in range `1-9`. And since you want to match number from `1 to 59`, you will be missing is numbers like `10,20,30,40,50` as pointed out in one comment.

Comment: @bobblebubble: Retracted the regex as checking with juno_okyo's function is correct and efficient.